# can you get var name from object with nested objects with lodash?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

https://jsfiddle.net/adamchenwei/Lyg2jy61/7/

**RESOLVED VERSION:**
https://jsfiddle.net/adamchenwei/Lyg2jy61/10/

For some reason [findKey](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#findKey) for parent top level got `undefined`
My objective is to get the result = 'myName' with lodash;

```js
    var obj = {
     myName: {
       Adam: 'Man',
      },
      herName: {
       Eve: 'Woman',
      },
    };
    
    var result = _.findKey(obj, '0'); //as you can see somehow its undefined!
    
    var result2 = _.findKey(obj.myName, '0');
    
    console.log(result);//objective is to get the result = 'myName' with lodash;
    
    console.log(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What makes you think you wouldn't get `undefined`? [That isn't how `findKey` works.](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#findKey)

Comment: @MikeC see the result from `result2`

Comment: What did you expect to actually get with that code?

Comment: @Ezeewei I see it. You don't have any objects with a property `'0'` which is truthy.

Comment: @vlaz copy the comment in my code to the question.

Comment: @MikeC I do not understand.... my Name is the `0` no?

Comment: @Ezeewei my point was that you could have put that information _in_ the question.

Comment: @Ezeewei Perhaps you're looking for [`_.keys`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#keys)? I don't understand how you think `0` will get you `myName` unless you mean to get each of the keys and accessed the `0th` one.

Comment: @MikeC that's how I thought it was

Comment: @Ezeewei Nope. Read the documentation more carefully. `findKey` returns the key of an object whose value matches some predicate. In your case, you're essentially saying "find me the key of the object who has a property of `0` which is a truthy value"

Comment: @MikeC _.keys return my an array of two keys... why can't I just return first one?

Comment: @Ezeewei You can if you do `_.keys(obj)[0]` or [`_.first(_.keys(obj))`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#head) if you wanted to go full lodash.

Comment: what if _.keys(obj) return undefined? then it will generate error, I try to make it error prove without ann if statement

Comment: @Ezeewei It isn't going to. It's always going to be an array, it just might be empty. Just test it out and see.

Comment: @Ezeewei it doesn't return `undefined` it will return an empty array at most

Comment: @MikeC thanks! thats very helpful

Comment: @MikeC why dont you include your answer ? I will mark yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you're actually trying to do is get the first key of an object. To get the keys of an object, you can use [`_.keys`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#keys). Then just retrieve the first one.

```js
var obj = {
  myName: {
    Adam: 'Man',
  },
  herName: {
    Eve: 'Woman',
  },
};

console.log(_.keys(obj)[0]);

// Or if you want to do it exclusively with lodash functions
console.log(_.first(_.keys(obj)));

// or
console.log(_.head(_.keys(obj)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're after exactly, but using `_.findKey` on the object you have posted would work like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lyg2jy61/8/

```
var obj = {
    myName: {
        Adam: 'Man',
    },
    herName: {
        Eve: 'Woman',
    }
};

console.log(_.findKey(obj, function(o) { return !!o.Adam; }));
```

If you just want the first key: `_.keys(obj)[0]`